# Custom image size in the_content loop

Tags: post-thumbnails, the-content, images

I changed the default image dimensions for the "large" thumbnail and re-generated my images using a plugin. The new image size is only shown on new posts created after the image size was created.

How do I make the old posts use the new image size too? They currently use the "large" thumbnail dimensions that were set and generated prior.

Answer (score -1):

This simply doesn't work.

Wordpress resizes the images while uploading, so if you don't upload them again, nothing will happen.

Comment: This doesn't work *out of the box*, but that is what this site is for, isn't it?